# Javascript quiz: Cannot activate next question when next button is clicked

Tags: javascript, api, events

I've just started learning Vanilla JS and im working a quiz using an API and i need you help!

I want to be able to click the "next button" and the next question appears but I am having trouble accessing the API questions.

Hope this makes sense. please let me know if further clafication is needed! Thanks!

```js
let apiUrl = " https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=150";

function showQuestion(response) {
  console.log(response);
  console.log(response.data.results[0].question);
  let question = document.querySelector("#question");
  question.innerHTML = response.data.results[0].question;
}

axios.get(apiUrl).then(showQuestion);

function showNextQuestion(response) {
  console.log(response.data.results);
}

function nextQuestion() {
  let apiUrl = " https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=150";
  axios.get(apiUrl).then(showNextQuestion);
}

let nextButton = document.querySelector("#next");
nextButton.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/adi/Desktop/SheCodes Resources/Quiz Game/style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Quiz</h1>
    <h2>
      Question:
      <div class="question" id="question">What is your name?</div>
    </h2>
    <span></span><button id="next">Next</button></span>
    <button id="answerButton">Answer</button>
    <h3 id="answer">Adodoola</h3>
    <script src="/Users/adi/Desktop/SheCodes Resources/Quiz Game/app4.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling

```
axios.get(apiUrl).then(showQuestion);
```

you have 150 questions. Just store result into function

```
let questions = [];
axios.get(apiUrl).then(function(response) {
    questions = response.data.results;
});
```

then add global counter like

```
let questionIndex = 0;
```

and work with it

```
function showNextQuestion() {
  console.log(questions[questionIndex]);
}

function nextQuestion() {
  questionIndex++;
  showNextQuestion();
}
```

Result:

```
let apiUrl = " https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=150";

let questions = [];
let questionIndex = 0;

axios.get(apiUrl).then(function(response) {
    questions = response.data.results;
});


function showQuestion() {
  let question = document.querySelector("#question");
  question.innerHTML = questions[questionIndex];
}

function nextQuestion() {
  questionIndex++;
  showQuestion();
}

let nextButton = document.querySelector("#next");
nextButton.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);
```